# AS3 Form Inquiry

Tags: actionscript-3, runtime-error

I am relatively new to AS3. I am having a few code issues at the moment i am hoping for some advice on this forum. 
Basically, i am creating a form for my website. I have one combobox and I want The user enter their email address and password into the fields. 
Then click on the submit button to sign in and to validate what they entered is correct. When i run my code in real-time i get an error
1120: Access of undefined property status_Txt. I dont know what status_Txt means.
I copied a large section of this code from a tutorial i read. My code is below: Can someone please tell me how i can resolve this problem.

```
 import flash.net.URLVariables;
 import flash.net.URLRequest;
 import flash.net.URLLoader;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import fl.data.DataProvider;
 import flash.events.Event;

 //Building the variables
 var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

 //Requesting the php file
 var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.example.com");
 phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

 phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;

 //Building the loader
 var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
 phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);

 //Variables ready for processing
 phpVars.email = txt_input.text;
 phpVars.p_swd = pass.text;

 phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);

 btn_one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnHandler);

 function btnHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
trace("Login success");
 }

 //Validate form fileds
 function showResult(event:Event):void{
     status_Txt.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
     trace(event.target.data.systemResult);

 }

 var cbox:Array = new Array();
 boy[0] = "Male";
 girl[1] = "Female";

 c_one.dataProvider = new DataProvider(cbox);
 c_one.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, dataHandler);

 function dataHandler(e:Event):void{
trace(e.target.value);
 }




 }
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access an object that doesn't exist. `status_Txt` is being referenced in:

```
function showResult(event:Event):void{
    status_Txt.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult; //Either remove this or add a textfield to the stage with the instance name status_Txt
    trace(event.target.data.systemResult);
}
```